# pine sometimes not update new received emails

Tags: linux, email, kubuntu

I am using pine on a KUbuntu linux email server to check my emails. Most of the time when I am under "Inbox", the list of emails is updated automatically so I don't have to do things like pushing the refresh button when I am under web. But sometimes it does not and I have to type "<" to go to the upper level and then select "Inbox" to enter again into the inbox directory to find out that I do receive new emails that are not shown previously. I was wondering what the problem is?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 2):

Hmm hmm. What about Alpine? By the way turning back to pine.. I'd go with source.
`apt-get build-dep pine` # will grab all the build dependencies
Download pine from the official homepage and use the old method. (Maybe Debian/Ubuntu applied some patch which  made this.)